# TYPO3 Extbase code for pi_getLL?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

in pi based Extension I have: `$this->pi_getLL('languagekey')` to get my translated variable.

What is the Extbase code for that?

I know how to do this in Fluid Template, but I need it in the Repository.

Comment: To moderators: please don't close or downvote it, as it's correct Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [this clue](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/1-localizing-and-internationalizing-an-extension.html), it suggests that this should work:

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Localization::translate($key, $extensionName, $arguments=NULL)
```

that should do the trick as well:

```
$GLOBALS['LANG']->sL('LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang.xml:cms_layout.not_configured');
```

BTW, sometimes easiest solution is checking how does ViewHelper which you know work. As I can see `Translate` VH uses the same method, check it in `render(...)` method of:

> /typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/TranslateViewHelper.php

Comment: Hey, thank you, it worked with: Tx_Extbase_Utility_Localization::translate($key, $extensionName);

Comment: The link to the clue is a dead one.

Comment: Hi there Tx_Extbase_Utility_Localization::translate($key, $extensionName); this is not worked in 6.2.6 version

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3 6.2x or later, you can get label in controller like this:

> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('your_label_key','your_extensionName');